# Make keyboard visible on launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How do I make the keyboard pop up when a view launches? There is a UITextField set up.

Answer (score 2):

Try to place somewhere after creating UITextField (probaly in viewDidLoad)

```
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
```